# Could not load file or assembly 'skmMenu' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: .net, html, visual-studio

I'm getting this error when trying to load a .NET app in Visual Studio. For some reason Visual Studio is having difficulty loading skmmenu which is a user control.  Is this not part of Visual Studio?

> Could not load file or assembly 'skmMenu' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This is the code I am using:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1" Namespace="skmMenu" Assembly="skmMenu" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

skmMenu is not a library in the .NET Framework.

You are missing the assembly that contains the namespace skmMenu, or you have the wrong namespace mentioned to begin with.

If you do have the library in the bin folder, and it still isn't working, and the control relies on an x32 library, this can cause a failure.

To fix that issue, set your target platform to x32.

Link: http://www.skmmenu.com/menu/  That's the link to the site which creates skmMenu.

Comment: there is an xml file in the bin folder called skmmenu.xml which is the strange thing... it's referenced in .aspx masterpage and .cs 
private void Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, 
skmMenu.MenuItemClickEventArgs e)